# Port-forwarding traffic to remote server using iptables

Tags: iptables, openvpn, nat

I'm struggling to set up an infrastructure where MySQL replication traffic from an Amazon RDS instance is forwarded over an OpenVPN link to a second server.

There is an Ubuntu EC2 instance running OpenVPN, with a tunnel to the MySQL server in another infrastructure.  If I've understood `iptables` correctly, it should be possible to forward traffic received on port 3306 to port 3306 on another (remote) IP, and reverse the process for returning traffic.

The setup looks like this:

```
|<--------- VPC ---------->|<-- internet -->|<--- Datacenter --->|


 RDS --> Public ip: 10.11.12.13
         EC2 instance
         VPC ip: 1.2.3.4               
                    OpenVPN ==== tunnel ===> MySQL server
                                             public ip: 9.10.11.12
                                             vpn ip: 5.6.7.8
```

Both the RDS and EC2 instances are in the same VPC, and I can connect from the EC2 instance to the MySQL server over the OpenVPN link with no problem at all - so the OpenVPN part seems to be working fine:

```
ssh root@5.6.7.8
mysql -uuser -p -h5.6.7.8
```

I've tried configuring `iptables` to do the port forwarding, but with no success. My current rules look like:

```
$ iptables -L

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination

Chain INET-PRIV (0 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
```

and

```
$ iptables -t nat -L -n

Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3306 to:5.6.7.8:3306
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3306 to:5.6.7.8:3306

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
SNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            5.6.7.8             tcp dpt:3306 to:1.2.3.4
```

Can anyone suggest where I'm going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Did enable IP-Forwarding in your Kernel?

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

This should return 1 if it's enabled and 0 if it's disabled.
If 0, do (as root)

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Also, why do you have two PREROUTING rules for the same destination (shouldn't be an issue though)?

Aside from that your rules are correct, it will probably work as soon as you enable ip_forward.

Another hint: use policy accept in forward and input only for testing purposes.

To help you along, this script should set some safer policies and include your Forwarding. I kept SSH in as to not lock you out, customize to fit your needs (e.g. add rules for your vpn etc.).

```
#!/bin/sh

# Enable IP-Forwarding
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward


### DEFAULT FIREWALL SETTINGS

# Flush all tables
iptables -F
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -X

# Set default policy to drop
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

# Allow local process communication (optional, required for some services)
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

# Allow established and related connections
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Allow outgoing connections
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT


### CUSTOM FIREWALL SETTINGS

# SSH (optional)
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT

# MySQL Forwarding:
# Allow forwarding to 5.6.7.8 on port 3306
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 3306 -d 5.6.7.8 -j ACCEPT

# Set NAT from 1.2.3.4:3306 to 5.6.7.8:3306
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 3306 -j DNAT --to-destination 5.6.7.8:3306
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 5.6.7.8 --dport 3306 -j SNAT --to-source 1.2.3.4
```

Edit: Oh and disable IPv6 if you don't use it.

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful! Unfortunately I'm still not getting a connection to the MySQL end - one thing I realised is that the diagram above was missing the public ElasticIP address from the EC2 instance. Could that be affecting things?

Comment: It really shouldn't matter since with the VPN you essentially created a Private Network (duh). But I kinda forgot about your VPN setup to be honest, is it site to site with fixed VPN-IPs? I assumed that 1.2.3.4 is the IP your 10.11.12.13-server has in the VPN. When you connect to your SQL-server over VPN you of course have to give iptables your VPN IP in the source-NAT `--to-source` option. In fact when correctly set up, your two servers should be in the same vpn subnet.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to bring this old post back alive.

This work's great. And I have another set of rules that also work for my test case.

However, I do not want to use the 'middle' machine to get to the SQL server unless you are doing a ssh localForward prior. Other wise, anyone that about that 'pivot' would get 'access' to the destination.

So, how to achieve that....